# postgres script silently pass without any result

Tags: postgresql

i am trying to execute psql queries from the bash command line passing password in following format

```
set PGPASSWORD=rtttttul psql -U ostgres -h localhost -d postgres -c "select * from logs" -o output.txt
```

Somehow my queries are not giving any results.i have tried to pass different queries or incorrect credentials but still script execute without any error.

If i don't pass password and try logging in to command prompt,everything works fine.
i want to check what basic thing i am missing above

Comment: Remove the `set`.

Comment: thanks u saved my day..u can put it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below command worked

```
PGPASSWORD=rtttttul psql -U ostgres -h localhost -d postgres -c "select * from logs" -o output.txt
```

remove **set** at start of command fixed it